# Providing Hive support to a deployed Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I need to use Hive-specific features in Spark SQL, however I have to work with an already deployed Apache Spark instance that, unfortunately, doesn't have Hive support compiled in.

What would I have to do to include Hive support for my job?

I tried using the [spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore) setting, but then I always get these exceptions:

> DataNucleus.Persistence: Error creating validator of type org.datanucleus.properties.CorePropertyValidator
>   ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}

and

> org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has not been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.

In the setting I am providing a fat-jar of [spark-hive](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hive_2.10/1.5.2) (excluded [spark-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10/1.5.2) and [spark-sql](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.5.2)) with all its optional Hadoop dependencies (CDH-specific versions of hadoop-archives, hadoop-common, hadoop-hdfs, hadoop-mapreduce-client-core, hadoop-yarn-api, hadoop-yarn-client and hadoop-yarn-common).

I am also specifying [spark.sql.hive.metastore.version](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#interacting-with-different-versions-of-hive-metastore) with the value 1.2.1

I am using CDH5.3.1 (with Hadoop 2.5.0) and Spark 1.5.2 on Scala 2.10